# A question about reviewer's comment

Tags: peer-review, journals

I have recieved a comment from a reviewer as
'You had less than 100 cases per division in Table 3, so you should only report with less than three significant " .
I could not understand what she/he wanted me to correct in [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cr1hx.png)

Answer (score 3):

The reviewer is probably talking about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

If you are reporting numbers like 3.23436, you likely have far too many significant figures: you are reporting precision that just isn't relevant. Report something like 3.2 instead.

In your table you have percentages. Round numbers like 40.6% to 41% throughout. And be consistent either with number of decimals (round to nearest 1%) or sig digits (12% and 3.5% both have 2 significant digits).